# how to convert password from dnn4 to dnn6

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-imc

i need to import all users from a dnn 4 site to dnn 5 site.i have already imported all tables.but in membership table the password encryption is different for dnn4 and dnn5.
i have register the same user in both sites.and the password and passwordsalt are different in version 4 and 5.so while import users  from dnn 4 to 5,i cannot login to the new site.

How to decrypt the old password and encrypt the same for new one?

Answer (score 1):

checking for machine key value in web.config and matching them may solve the problem

Comment: i changed the machine key in webconfig and now both are same.i give same password.but the encoded password is different.why?

Answer (score 1):

Between 4 and 6 (really between any installs) one of the best things is to have one of the user manager tools that allows you to export users with password and import them into another portal or install.

As an alternative -

1. make a copy of the dnn 4 site
2. upgrade the dnn 4 site to dnn 6 (or whatever version you like)
3. now copy the machine key etc over to other site and copy in users

Something like the alternative is not really clean and prone to problems (especially if the portal already has users - like the host)

Comment: in my situation,the site is completed with new design and some more functionality.so i cannot upgrade the old site.i need to manually import all users from old site.any ideas

Comment: http://store.dotnetnuke.com/home/product-list/searchtext/import - some of the tools here might help

Comment: I think the onyaktech module is about the cheapest but I have experience with http://store.dotnetnuke.com/home/product-details/bulk-user-manager-v32 - I do not know of a free one